# Play JSON serialize/deserialize case class with one argument by skipping it

Tags: playframework-2.0, play-json

I have the following objects:

```
case class Foo(value: UUID)
case class Bar(foo: Foo)
```

And I would like to have them serialized like this in JSON:

```
{foo: "e88ad5ea-13cf-4666-addb-c231c12cd3a3"}
```

Meaning I want to omit the "value" argument added by the automatic formatter if I simply write this:

```
implicit val fooFormat = Json.format[Foo]
implicit val barFormat = Json.format[Bar]
```

I tried writing my custom writers/readers but I do not really know how to skip a JPath.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
implicit val format: Format[Bar] = new Format[Bar] {
   override def writes(o: Bar): JsValue = Json.obj("foo" -> o.foo.value)

override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Bar] =
  (json \ "foo").validate[String].map(s => Bar(Foo(UUID.fromString(s))))
}
```

Comment: Yes I guess that would work. But in my concrete case, Bar has actually a lot of other parameters, and I would have preferred not to have to write all the writes/reads.